# How to fix JaCoCo reportDir is deprecated

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

Gradle 7.1

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco")
}
```

How to replace the statement with reportsDir to hide warning about deprecated feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried checking the plugin's documentation? As you can see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) the `reportsDir` property seems to have been replaced by `reportsDirectory`.

Also the [`JacocoPluginExtension`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/plugins/JacocoPluginExtension.html) documentation mentions that the `reportsDirectory` property is the one to be used for setting the output directory.

Comment: Thanks! This is the problem with documentation. I didn't find an information on JaCoCo site and I start google. I've got a lot of results and all was outdated and incorrect. I didn't even realize that I should look at gradle site. Now it works fine. Moreover I just removed that line and use defaults.